# NgxNotification Component fails in production build. Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, dev-to-production

I used NgxNotificationComponent in App Module. This works fine in the ng serve. But when I try to build the app using ng build --prod it throws an error.

```
ERROR in : Type NgxNotificationComponent in /Development/web- 
angular/node_modules/ngx-notification/ngx-notification.d.ts is part of 
the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in /Development/web- 
angular/src/app/app.module.ts and NgxNotificationModule in 
/Development/web-angular/node_modules/ngx-notification/ngx- 
notification.d.ts! Please consider moving NgxNotificationComponent in 
/Development/web-angular/node_modules/ngx-notification/ngx- 
notification.d.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in 
/Development/web-angular/src/app/app.module.ts and 
NgxNotificationModule in /Development/web-angular/node_modules/ngx- 
notification/ngx-notification.d.ts. You can also create a new NgModule 
that exports and includes NgxNotificationComponent in /Development/web- 
angular/node_modules/ngx-notification/ngx-notification.d.ts then import 
that NgModule in AppModule in /Development/web- 
angular/src/app/app.module.ts and NgxNotificationModule in 
/Development/web-angular/node_modules/ngx-notification/ngx- 
notification.d.ts
```

Do I have to change the node module itself or are there any work arounds.

Versions are following

```
"ngx-notification": "^1.0.5",
```

Dev Dependencies

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
"@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import in you app.module.ts not a *NgxNotificationComponent* to declarations but a *NgxNotificationModule* to imports. The documentation is not quite right.
 It works in production:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxNotificationModule} from 'ngx-notification';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxNotificationModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```